# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server? ocelot.aul.fiu.edu

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have googled and even searched for this error here on Stack Overflow to no avail. Most people facing this error are setting up their on localhost servers, or using Apache, but my error is a bit more specific than that.

I am suppose to sign in to phpMyAdmin using my university credentials to ocelot.aul.fiu.edu server.

I am using the correct information yet the error persist, what can I do to further troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: It sounds like the mysql administrative tables are not configured to let you access the databases.  This is host and user tables in the mysql database. You have to be root or whatever high privileges user to edit these tables.   If you have one, can you connect using a mysql client command line and your credentials?

Comment: How would I go about connecting using 'mysql client command line'? I'm sorry I'm new at this and using mysql and phpmyadmin specifically. I'm kind of lost.

Comment: You would need an account and terminal window on the host server. 
mysql -u yourid -p      it will then prompt for your password

I think you will need to contact the mysql/system administrator about getting access.  Is there a FAQ for you to use?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ask your professor or tech support folks for assistance. That particular error message can indicate that either the MySQL server is not reachable by your client (which is generally expected if you're running phpMyAdmin on your local machine as most hosts don't allow customers to connect from an external address) or that your username and password are incorrect.

If you're running phpMyAdmin on the university server, you can double-check your username and password. If you're running it on your local machine, then you can check with the system administrator to make sure that external connections are permitted directly to MySQL. One of those is likely to be the culprit here.